# Redux saga - can't dispatch action: __webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function

Tags: redux, redux-saga

I am trying to dispatch an action in a saga function in this way:

```
yield put(addToCart(item));
```

When trying to execute it, it gives the error `__webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function`.

"`addToCart`" is an action creator which I imported:

```
  export const addToCart = product => ({
        type: types.ADD_TO_CART,
        payload: { product },
    });
```

This action never fires.

The `item` (or `product`) is an object, like :

```
{
    'id' : 5,
     'thing' : 'stuff'
}
```

(+ other properties).

I can dispatch other actions, but this one doesn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I had imported the action creator wrongly:

```
import addToCart  from './actionCreators'
```

It should be:

```
import { addToCart } from './actionCreators'
```

But what kind of error is `"__webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function"` ? The error messages are worthless, they give you no clue at what the error is about.